# Magento 2: getting error for all pages We can't create the Wish List right now

Tags: magento2

***php bin/magento setup:upgrade***

```
 Undefined index: wishlist in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152
```

display error on frontend

> We can't create the Wish List right now.

Comment: Have you checked whether wishlist table exists or not?

Comment: @aravind  not exists

Comment: This error occurs because wishlist table gets deleted somehow..

Comment: check other magento instance there will be table for wishlist

Comment: @aravind right, thanks  i will check

Comment: there is a temporary fix for this.. But after this fix you need to create  that wishlist table manually with same fields  in other magento instance

Comment: check this please https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/368409/55221

Answer (score 2):

In the core file,

> vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php

In the below condition add a if condition and execute the upgrade command.

After executing create the wishlist table and remove the condition. And execute other commands to ensure it is working fine.

```
/**
  * Process references for all tables. Schema validation required.
  *
  * @param  Table[] $tables
  * @param Schema $schema
  */
  private function processReferenceKeys(array $tables, Schema $schema)
  {
      foreach ($tables as $table) {
          $tableName = $table->getName();
          if ($schema->getTableByName($tableName) instanceof Table) {
              continue;
          }
          $referencesData = $this->dbSchemaReader->readReferences($tableName, $table->getResource());
          $references = [];

          foreach ($referencesData as $referenceData) {
              //Prepare reference data
              if($tableName != 'wishlist') {
                  $referenceData['table'] = $table;
                  $referenceTableName = $referenceData['referenceTable'];
                  $referenceData['column'] = $table->getColumnByName($referenceData['column']);
                  $referenceData['referenceTable'] = $this->tables[$referenceTableName];
                  $referenceData['referenceColumn'] = $referenceData['referenceTable']->getColumnByName(
                      $referenceData['referenceColumn']
                  );
                  $references[$referenceData['name']] = $this->elementFactory->create('foreign', $referenceData);
                  //We need to instantiate tables in order of references tree
                  if (isset($tables[$referenceTableName]) && $referenceTableName !== $tableName) {
                    $this->processReferenceKeys([$referenceTableName => $tables[$referenceTableName]], $schema);
                      unset($tables[$referenceTableName]);
                  }
              }
            }

            $table->addConstraints($references);
            $schema->addTable($table);
        }
    }
```

Comment: condition add a if condition and execute the upgrade command  not working same error display

Comment: I have updated the code pls check now..

Comment: did the error still occur?

Answer (score 0):

Check this table exists in your DB.
I faced the same situation after replacing live DB in my local host.
further investigation noticed some tables are missing from the dump.